# How do I get the value of each key pressed and use it in a variable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

How do I get the value of each key pressed and use it in a variable with jQuery? I want to get a key pressed and reveal a certain picture on the page that correlates to that key right when it is pressed. I also ONLY want to target A-Z and "."

Thanks!

Comment: what have u tried so far? post ur code ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can use the `keypress` event, and then convert the character to a string, and match it against your criteria.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uMjAA/1/):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (s.match(/[a-zA-Z\.]/))
        console.log(s + ' is a match!');
});
```

**Update:** For the key pressed inside another element, just use the selector `$('#LearnStart')`, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uMjAA/2/).

Comment: I don't understand how to use this.. I am very new to jQuery and have used it only a little. How do I get the key that was pressed inside of a field with an ID of "#LearnStart"

Comment: AWESOME I GOT IT! THANK YOU! How do I recognize if the backspace was clicked, and remove the picture put on the page?

Answer (score 0):

heres a link for jquery [Keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) function and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

avoid having ids preceeding with #. with an input of id  LearnStar you can insert a script like this:

```
$("#LearnStar").live("keypress",function(e)
{
    var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (s.match(/[a-zA-Z\.]/))
        console.log(s + ' is a match!');
});
```

The live event basically takes care of the fact that if the control is rendered on the page after the script has been loaded.

You can do nifty stuff with this like prevent the user from typing non valid keys by using 
`e.preventDefault()` and returning false from the callback function.

Comment: How do I store the backspace as a variable and the spacebar?